# Remove all lines in a data set >= a value

Tags: python, file, text-parsing

I have an extensive data set of over 400,000 lines. Here is an example of the dataset:

```
40005 1583274133
40000 1583274134
40004 1583274135
40004 1583274136
160 1583274137
40005 1583274137
40006 1583274138
40003 1583274139
40001 1583274140
40003 1583274141
40003 1583274142
```

I need to remove any line's that start with a number greater than or equal to 40000. It is particle physics data for muon decay rates, so anything over 40000 nanoseconds is basically useless. I know how to open and write files, I am just not sure what the most efficient way to get rid of all of the lines with 40000 or greater as the first column is. File is a text file separated by tabs.

Comment: do you know how to iterate over a file object? if so iterate over the file and for each line check if it fits your criteria don’t write it out to a new file.

Comment: Do you want a solution in pandas or native Python? Can we assume you can read in all 400K lines at once, or in chunks of say 64KB? (By the way you can also do all this on the command-line with a one-line `grep` with a regex, frankly I'd do that)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a plain Python solution which processes the input line-by-line, so it doesn' t have scaling problems with memory usage:

```
with open(in_file) as f_in, open(out_file, 'w') as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        if int(line.split()[0]) < 40000: #checking the condition
            f_out.write(line)
```

Comment: removed my downvote, be aware you can use a with statement for the “w” file as well on the same line where you open the input file. not sure if you know that.

Answer (score 0):

### Use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/)

- Pandas is ideal for dealing with columnar data
- Two lines of code that doesn't require iterating over every row
- Makes visualizations easy.
- Read in multiple file formats: [pandas: IO tools (text, CSV, HDF5, …)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html)

```py
import pandas as pd

# read in your data
df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep='\t')

    time    value
0   40005   1583274133
1   40000   1583274134
2   40004   1583274135
3   40004   1583274136
4   160     1583274137
5   40005   1583274137
6   40006   1583274138
7   40003   1583274139
8   40001   1583274140
9   40003   1583274141
10  40003   1583274142


# filter the data
# assigning the filtered data back to df keeps only the desired data
# if you want to maintain all the data, use a different variable
df = df[df['time'] < 40000]

# save df
df.to_csv('filtered.txt', sep='\t', index=False)

print(df)

    time    value
4   160     1583274137
```

### Memory usage:

- Despite the comments, it's fine to load that much data into memory, otherwise how would we do Big Data.
- It's only to much if you don't have enough RAM.
- As shown, for a `dataframe` of this size, `memory usage: 6.1 MB`.
- [Dask](https://dask.org/), which has an API similar to pandas, can handle much larger datasets.

```py
time = [*range(400000)]
value = [*range(1583234128, 1583634128)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': time, 'value': value})

print(df.head())

time    value
0   1583234128
1   1583234129
2   1583234130
3   1583234131
4   1583234132

print(df.tail())

time    value
399995  1583634123
399996  1583634124
399997  1583634125
399998  1583634126
399999  1583634127

print(df.info())

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 400000 entries, 0 to 399999
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count   Dtype
---  ------  --------------   -----
 0   time    400000 non-null  int64
 1   value   400000 non-null  int64
dtypes: int64(2)
memory usage: 6.1 MB
```

Comment: I would avoid loading everything into memory with 400000 lines of data.

Comment: 400,000 lines isn't that much and the data is only 2 columns.  I load multiple datafiles from an oscilloscope into memory all at once and they are 1.25M rows.